# Give an alias to field name on ::find('all')

Tags: sql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have a field on Database called `name` but when I retrieve this I would that be called `label`.

In raw `SQL` I can do that like this:

```
  SELECT name AS label FROM ...
```

Theres a "quick way" to do this on `find` without need to deal with `entity`, `virtual fields` etc...

Comment: So your question is _not_ about SQL column aliases and the CakePHP ORM?

Comment: Yes but I'm asking about how to do it on cakephp so I don't think an expert on SQL could help. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, AFAICT, tags aren't _that_ exclusive, just because a question doens't need an SQL expert, that doesn't mean that using the SQL tag would be inappropriate, at least not when combined with other tags to form more specific "compound categories", otherwise we would end up needing ugly tags like `cakephp-orm-sql-aliases` ;) Tags also make searching easier, and they are also a factor for generating related links (the link-list on the right hand side).

Comment: Anyhow, why aren't virtual properties an option? Doing this on query level has its drawbacks.

Comment: Can you give me an example how I can do it using virtual properties?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using **virtual properties** like this on `Entity`:

```
protected $_virtual = ['label'];

protected function _getlabel()
{
    return $this->_properties['name'];
}
```

A potential gotcha could be... I'm was using `_serialize` to return the result and it was not working because you have to expose the **virtual properties** using `$_virtual`.